# Nomenclature of configuration values which represent physical properties

Tags: configuration, nomenclature

I encounter many configuration values in the software I develop. I am looking for a term to call configuration points that map to physical properties. E.g, the height of a tunnel.

The context would be around validating the logical v.s. actual height. In this case the configuration value for the height of the tunnel must be less than or equal to the actual height. If this configuration is taller than the actual height you will crash.

Answer (score 0):

A suitable name for the example configuration variable might be `maxHeight`. If you want a generic term to refer to configuration variables that specify min/max sizes, weights, available colours and so on, then perhaps the term *constraints* would be appropriate. Or if you want a term to refer to configuration variables that merely describe a physical object, then *properties* might be appropriate.